# Programatically splitting items in a list fragment equally

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a list fragment on the left as shown, clicking on which will show content on the right.

[image]

I need to split the list so the the whole list on the left is covered and equally occupied by items in the list. So for four items, the list is split equally into four parts and if three, split equaly into three parts. I've seen similar questions on SO, but not particularly this , how can this be done, is it possible to hack something without having to revincent the listview and write my own class(which I would do normally, but cant in the interest of time)?

I am just creating a simple list that occupies the whole length of the fragmented screen and attaching an adapter to it.

```
Collections.sort(Constants.studyLogCollection);
        ListAdapter myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                Constants.studyLogCollection);
```

List:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/bg"
         android:paddingLeft="8dp"
         android:paddingRight="8dp">

     <ListView
         android:id="@id/android:list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
     </ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if I get your mean correctly, you need write your own adapter

Comment: Normally I would, but assuming we don't have any time, is there a way to do it without the custom class?

Comment: sorry i don't know any other solution but create custom adapter take 10 minute almost, its not too much

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to fill the whole height of the view, you can use LinearLayout and make it's layout height match_parent

*if you use ListView, you need to make every row of the list to have match_parent as height..

If you give us some code we can help you adjust it..

Comment: Well basically its just one list view that occupies the whole length of the fragmented screen and Im populating it with a list adapter

Comment: try making every row of the list to have match_parent as height..and put your list view inside LinearLayout and make it's layout height match_parent

Comment: That might not be a bad idea, let me try it and get back, thanks :)

Comment: Yikes well actually it already is that, so Ive tried it already, doesnt work :/

Comment: try make your list view's height 0dp and give it a weight of 1

Comment: @MatanDahan for changing high of row OP must change height of list item, not `listView`